# Accessing Apache environment variables from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I have a requirement to access apache environment variable from js file. I am not sure this is possible or not.

I used to set Apache variables and access it in php using the following way

Set ENV varialbe

```
SetEnv PAYPAL_MODE live
```

From php

```
echo $_SERVER["PAYPAL_MODE"];
```

My question is can i access "PAYPAL_MODE" in my js file

```
<html>
  <head>
    alert(PAYPAL_MODE);
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the javascript created by a php page or is it stored in its own file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<head>
    <script>
        alert("<?= $_SERVER["PAYPAL_MODE"];?>");
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var paypal_mode = "<?= $_SERVER["PAYPAL_MODE"];?>";
alert(paypal_mode);
```

You need to be sure that you want expose that variable

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this in your html :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.paypal_mode = <?php echo json_encode($_SERVER["PAYPAL_MODE"]); ?>;
});
</script>
```

And access it through the window object in your javascript file.